Using Metric Labels as Dynamic Limits in Grafana Expressions
I have an application where I want to export metrics with expected limits. The goal is to automate the creation of alerts and set triggered limits.
Ideally, I’d like to add an additional tag with the expected limit and use Grafana multi-alerts for this. However, there’s a limitation: the label_values function, which provides labels, uses a different API and isn’t available in expressions.
For instance, I have a metric like request.time.total{path="/index", q="95", limit="0.1"}. For each path value, I have a different expected limit, and I’d like to use the limit in an expression like this: sum(request.time.total{q="95"}) by (path) < ???(limit)???
I know that I could export the limit as a separate metric, but this seems costly, as Prometheus doesn’t have compression for static values.
Do you know of any other solutions for this issue? Thanks!
